# Bad performance when select any thing from a table on hive?

Tags: hive, cloudera

i have a partitioned and clustered table that contains around 24 million records, when i select count(*) from this table on hive it takes about 50 minutes to get the result, but when i dropped this table and created it againg the result of count got in 0.25 seconds.

i dont know what is the reason for this.

Is there any way to enhance the performance without dropping and recreating the table again?